# How can I replace preg_replace with preg_replace_callback in PHP5.4?

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.4, preg-replace-callback

I have a PHP page in which I am using following command:-

```
$abc = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "chr(\\1)", $abc);
```

Now I want to replace the above command with the "preg_replace_callback" function as preg_replace is deprecated in PHP 5.4 .

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try using anonymous functions like this :

```
$abc = preg_replace_callback(
    '/&#(\d+);/me',
    function ($match) 
    { 
        return chr($match[1]);
    },
    $abc
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I used the code you specified but I am getting an error in it saying:preg_replace_callback() "Requires argument 2, 'function($a) { return chr($a[1]); }', to be a valid callback"

Comment: Not sure why that was happening. Maybe $a is a reserved variable. Try the edited code.

Comment: Actually it is giving me error at the function keyword saying incorrect syntax.Do I need to put the entire thing in single quotes?

Comment: Not quite. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) requires it to be an actual function without quotes. Allow me to add indentation to the code.

Comment: Yup I too saw the definition. But I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Hey I sorted out the above mentioned issue. But now I am getting the error : "Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback"